# Tensorboard for Windows for Tensorflowsharp

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, tensorflowsharp

Is it posssible to run a standalone version of Tensorboard on Windows WITHOUT installing tensorflow and python.

I want to look at output from Tensorflowsharp only.

Comment: sry, i was wrong with my first answer. Maybe this helps you: https://github.com/zihaolucky/tensorboard-distro

Answer (score 0):

There is a standalone version. You can find it [here](https://github.com/dmlc/tensorboard).